# Autowire a bean requiring another bean for its object creation

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, javabeans, autowired

I have a class which has following autowiring

```
public class XYZ {

@Autowired
private Principal principal;

public void main() {
AlexandriaDownloadSignatureUtilityV1 downloadSignatureUtilV1 =
                new AlexandriaDownloadSignatureUtilityV1(
                        getMaterialsetNameProvider(principal),
               
                );
}
}
```

I want to autowire AlexandriaDownloadSignatureUtilityV1 dependency, but since it is dependent on `pricipal` bean, can you please tell me how to do so?

Comment: Why not make `AlexandriaDownloadSignatureUtilityV1` a `@Component` so that it could have autowired beans itself? Or why not put instantiating the beans in `@Configuration`s within `@Bean` methods?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Component
public class XYZ {

@Autowired
private Principal principal;

public void main() {
AlexandriaDownloadSignatureUtilityV1 downloadSignatureUtilV1 =
                new AlexandriaDownloadSignatureUtilityV1(
                        getMaterialsetNameProvider(principal),
               
                );
}
}
```

Add @Component at the Top of the class this will create a bean of this object and inject their dependency also